# Why is being indent's wrong causes wrong function?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I cannot understand why this error happen.
First,I wrote

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os

def download_image(url,name):
    path = "./scrape_image/"
    imagename = str(name) + ".jpg"

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

        print(path)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,path+imagename)


url = "https://api.XXXkeyword=YYY&limit=1000"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
rss = response.read().decode("utf-8")

soup = BeautifulSoup(rss, "xml")

name=0
for s in soup.find_all("photo"):
    url = s.find_all("image_url")[0].string
    name+=1
    download_image(url, name)
```

by running this code,I can get 1 image from the API.But originally the right code can get 1000 images from the API.I fixed indents in the first code, so my code is like

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os

def download_image(url,name):
    path = "./image/"
    imagename = str(name) + ".jpg"

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    print(path)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path+imagename)
    time.sleep(1) 


url = "https://api.XXXkeyword=YYY&limit=1000"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
rss = response.read().decode("utf-8")

soup = BeautifulSoup(rss, "xml")

name = 0
for s in soup.find_all("photo"):
    url = s.find_all("image_url")[0].string
    name+=1
    download_image(url,name)
```

At last,I can get 1000 images from the API. But I cannot understand why I can do so by fixing the indent.Please give me some explanations.

Comment: Because it's Python...?

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first example you're only getting the image if your condition passes:

```
if not os.path.exists(path):
```

And that condition will only pass *once* because you immediately create the path:

```
os.makedirs(path)
```

For every other iteration of the loop, the condition is false.  So the code *within* the conditional block doesn't execute.

Basically, an `if` block only executes if the condition is true.  When you move your code *out* of the `if` block, it always executes regardless of the condition.